# Wordpress custom post type post and category links 404

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, pagination, 404-error

I've recently created several custom post types in a wordpress site, with the code below, they are generating links in the correct form e.g. root/category/id/postname but each link to the full post, pagination or category 404's.

I've tried a number of popular solutions, appending /%category%/%post_id%/ to the url structure, rewriting function names but I'm getting nowhere fast.

With the wordpress permalink structure set to default e.g. root/?page_id=1257 everything works ok.

Any effort to add additional parameters to rewrite (see below) produces "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'" even though no ';' is present.

```
'rewrite' => array(
'slug' => 'issue')
```

Any help appreciated - highly confused, very frustrated!

```
<?php

//      CUSTOM POST TYPE 1
add_action('init', 'mjwpress_register');

function mjwpress_register() {
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Press'),
        'singular_label' => __('Press'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'new_item' => __('New Press Item'),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats')
    );

    register_taxonomy('press-category', array('article'), 
        array(
            'label' => 'Press Story Category', 
            'singular_label' => 'press-story-category',
            'public' => TRUE,
            'show_tagcloud' => TRUE,
            'hierarchical' => TRUE,
            'query_var' => TRUE,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'rewrite' => TRUE)
    );

    register_post_type( 'mjwpress' , $args );
}


add_action('inthenews_init', 'inthenews_init');
add_action('save_post', 'save_mjwpress_options');

function inthenews_init(){
    add_meta_box('newsmeta', 'Press Options', 'mjwpress_meta_options', 'mjwpress', 'normal', 'low');

}

function mjwpress_meta_options(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $linkurl = $custom['linkurl'][0];
    $linktitle = $custom['linktitle'][0];
?>

<div class='form-wrap'>
    <div class='form-field'>
        <label for='linkurl'>Link to External Publication:</label>
        <input name='linkurl' value='<?php echo $linkurl; ?>' />
        <p>E.g. http://www.example.com/article-title.php</p>
    </div>

    <div class='form-field'>
        <label for='linktitle'>Title of External Publication:</label>
        <input name='linktitle' value='<?php echo $linktitle; ?>' />
        <p>E.g. Lib Dem Voice</p>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
}

function save_mjwpress_options(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'linkurl', $_POST['linkurl']);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'linktitle', $_POST['linktitle']);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flush your permalinks whenever you add/remove/modify a taxonomy or post type. You can do this in the backend by simply going to the permalinks page and resaving

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that and still have the same problem.

Comment: I'd also advise changing the name of the admin_init function, namespace clashes are not nice, and you should prefix all your functions for safety/compatibility

Comment: Also change your permalinks and test each configuration

Comment: Oddly enough it works with the default config, but everything else 404's!